# A CSV Import/Export wizard for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, csv, import, wizard

To avoid reinventing the wheel, I'm looking for some dialog wizard components/libraries that will simplify my job of importing CSV and similar text files into my Delphi/C++Builder application.

In other words, the user of our app can 'open' a suitable text file, and they can 'describe' through the UI how the columns are laid out and how the file columns relate to the datafields that our app offers.

Basic requirements:-

- Handle different newline styles
- Handle Tab, Comma and user-specified fixed-width columns
- User definable column ordering with visual preview of results
- Handle optional and mandatory columns

Extra goodies:-

- Be able to save all settings as a 'profile' that can be easily reapplied later.

Comment: This feels like write your own territory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try these two components

- [`EMS Advanced Data Import VCL`](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/tools/advancedimport)
  [image]
- [`EMS Advanced Data Export VCL`](http://www.sqlmanager.net/products/tools/advancedexport)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.  Have you used these yourself?

Comment: Yes @Roddy i been used these components in the past, and i fully recommend you :) .

Answer (score 3):

SMImport comes to mind : http://www.scalabium.com/

Answer (score 2):

My text streams classes in the unit CsiTextStreamsUnt.pas (you can download the utility classes at http://www.csinnovations.com/framework_utilities.htm) provide the basic functionality to cover everything you need. All you would need to do is develop the GUI.

Comment: Thanks, interesting. But I suspect the GUI part of the job could be the most time-consuming!

Comment: Fair enough - perhaps not the most time consuming, but certainly a significant component.